# Calling Qt functions with QString & parameters from SWIG

Tags: c++, qt, swig

I'm trying to wrap a Qt library in SWIG for both Python and PHP. The function signature that I'm having trouble with is:

```
bool myfunc(const QString &param1, const QString &param2="");
```

I've added the following typemap to the SWIG input file:

```
%typemap(in) QString {
    $1 = QString(PyString_AsString($input));
}
%typemap(out) QString {
    $result = PyString_FromString($1.toUtf8().constData());
}
```

and it compiles fine, but when I try to call it I get:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'myfunc'

Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    myfunc(QString const &)
    myfunc(QString const &,QString const &)
```

Comment: do you have also a `myfunc(QString const &)`?

Comment: No, the dual declaration is SWIG's way of dealing with the default value for the second parameter.